# Reading a text file in binary mode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am reading a text file in vb.net using binary mode but it is ignoring the spaces while reading from the files. Below is the snapshots of the code:

```
        Dim hInFile As Integer
        hInFile = FileSystem.FreeFile()
        FileSystem.FileOpen(hInFile, Filename, OpenMode.Binary)
        result = FileSystem.InputString(hInFile, FileSystem.LOF(hInFile))
        FileSystem.FileClose(hInFile)
```

and below is the line what is written inside the textfile:

Note: spaces means a simple space on that place

```
0000085190|spaces spaces spaces spaces spaces spaces ?|P.F.L.                   |                    spaces spaces spaces spaces spaces spaces ?|0000000000 |0000000000 |          ?|          ?|ZAN   |
```

While I am using above code to read above line(inside the file), it ignoring the spaces and giving me output as :

```
0000085190|                         |P.F.L.                   |                    ?|0000000000 |0000000000 |          ?|          ?|ZAN   |
```

Comment: My crystal ball says some of these are not spaces but tabs.  Use a hex viewer to see what is really there.

Comment: There's a note in the Microsoft documentation that `InputString` is effectively deprecated, and that there are better-supported ways to do the same thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.inputstring?view=net-6.0